Fixing unreadable coordinates in QGIS
I am using UTM 32 for Germany and want to add some coordinates but when I do that they are thick, overlapping and not readable.
I tried to adjust the size and font but that did not fix the problem. I noticed it is that way, whenever I use the shapefile of nuts.


I am using Qgis. Nuts is a geocode standard for referencing the administrative divisions of countries in europe. I want to add coordinates to the frame for reference.

Pics or it didn't happen! No, seriously: Screenshots are very helpful when it comes to determining problems like this.

How are you adding the coordinates? As labels to a set of points? As coordinates on a set of grid lines in the map composer? Do you have multiple overlapping points that's causing it to look thick and overlapping?

I would like to add the coordinates in the map composer

As provided as an answer, you are aking for one tick every one Unit, which for UTM is every meter. That explains the inconsistent display

The values for the interval need to be edited - here they are set to 100000:


@amelie if this answered your question you should accept it.
